# Using System.Collections.ArrayList from .NET in VB6

Tags: .net, vb6, com-interop, mscorlib

On my development machine and in the customer environment we've a Visual Basic 6 binary that does this:

```
dim x as object
set x = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
```

... it works as expected (we can add items to it, get the Count, etc).

Recently we installed a new Windows Server 2012 R2 machine (which has .NET 4.X as part of the OS). When I try to run the same VB6 binary on this machine, the above line gets the error:

> "Automation error"

If I add Reference to C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.tlb it still works on my local development machine

```
dim x as New ArrayList
x.Add("test")
x.Count ' 1
```

...but still gets the automation error on the 2012 server.

Is it possible the user running the binary (LocalSystem) doesn't have rights to use the DLL? I also tried running the binary with the same domain user which I use on my local machine.

Why this difference between the two computers / environments?

Comment: I thought perhaps I'd only .NET 64 bit installed, but I do have a few versions in this directory: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework

Comment: Some people suggest re-installing .NET 2.0 or 3.X. But when I try to do so on Server 2012 R2 I just get an error saying, "... couldn't be installed. Windows Server roles and features cannot automatically be installed or uninstalled via the Windows Features Control Panel" (despite the fact that I'm manually running an installer.

Comment: In my experience, these type of problems are related with app.config files. See these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47867724/3929185 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/41142221/3929185. Also use process hacker or procexp and determine which .net clr is being called: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rodneyviana/2014/12/23/identifying-the-net-version-you-are-running-2-0-4-5-4-5-1-or-4-5-2/

Comment: Sounds like an installation problem. Try to repair the components... Compare the following registry keys see if they look the same on your working machine: HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{6896B49D-7AFB-34DC-934E-5ADD38EEEE39} and HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\System.Collections.ArrayList

Comment: @froque app.config? This is a VB6 executable, there is no app.config.

Comment: @SimonMourier The first has different children, System.Collections.ArrayList only has a System.Collections.ArrayList\CLSID with value {6896B49D-7AFB-34DC-934E-5ADD38EEEE39} (which I imagine is a pointer to the first).

Comment: Children should be pretty much the same (minor clr version number and windows system32 path). Also, you should check 32 bit registry (I guess you're all x86, not x64), so it would be HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\WOW6432Node\CLSID\{6896B49D-7AFB-34DC-934E-5ADD38EEEE39}

Comment: @SimonMourier It's a 64bit system. I found the solution and answered my question.

Comment: @DeveloperWebs did you check the links I supplied? Your application maybe an VB6 executable but you are calling .NET code, which will look for an app.config file. Your answer below further confirms my suspicions.

Comment: @froque I did. I'm calling built-in .NET libraries. They don't have .config files do they (or at least none that I should mess with)? I found the solution. See the answer I added.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that .NET 4.X was installed with Windows. The IT fellow jut used the Add/Remove Windows features UI to install .NET 2.x and 3.x. I had previously tried to install them with the Microsoft web installer which failed. With .NET 2.x and 3.X installed the VB6 executable now correctly instantiates the System.Collections.ArrayList library and works without error. I suspect this means that .NET 4.x does not provide a COM interface.